# How to return a QuerySet of 2 models via reverse ForeignKey lookup in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have "Parameter" and "ParameterChoice" models where I define multiple choices for each parameter. The end goal is to have some sort of assessment where I have a list of parameters where each parameter has a specific fixed set of choices available for selection from a dropdown list within the HTML template.

I want to somehow pass one or two querysets to the template where I will render a table of all parameters and available choices next to it. Unfortunately, I really struggle to come up with logic in Django on how to achieve this. Ideally, result would look like this:

| Parameters | Choices |
| --- | --- |
| Param1 | `ChoiceA` `ChoiceB` `ChoiceC` |
| Param2 | `ChoiceY` `ChoiceZ` |

How can I make this happen without a raw SQL query?

Current setup:

models.py

```
class Parameter(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=200)

class ParameterChoices(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=200)
    parameter = models.ForeignKey(Parameter, related_name='parameterchoices', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
```

views.py

```
def parameters(request):
    params = Parameter.objects.all()
    param_choices = ParameterChoices.objects.all()
    context = {
        'parameters': params,
        'parameter_choices': param_choices,
    }
    return render(request, 'questionnaire/parameters.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have params mapped to their choices. to do so pass the context like this.

```
def parameters(request):
    params = Parameter.objects.all().prefetch_related("parameterchoices")
    all_params = [
       {
          'parameter': param,
          'choices': param.parameterchoices.all()
       }  for param in params
    ]

    context = {
      "params": all_params
    }
    return render(request, 'questionnaire/parameters.html', context)
```

So in the template, you can loop over on params and render their related choices.

> Note
> `prefetch_related` is optional. its their to boost performance and avoiding N+1 query problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It did seem to work, but I need to spend some more time in the morning to try and iterate properly the dictionary with a query set inside. Also, since I create a dictionary I lose access to objects. What would be the best way to pass `pk` for `'parameter': param,`? I use `pk` as a link to access a specific parameter view so preferably that would be part of the dictionary.

Comment: param is an object of model Parameter so pk is also part of that object. on the template u can user iterater_var.pk. the dictionary is there coz for mapping reason. u wont loose any thing on the model.